# Bloom filter tuned for small data sets

Tags: data-structures

All the bloom filter variants that I can find are optimized for large datasets. In fact, the [implementation and tests](https://github.com/FastFilter) for Xor and Binary Fuse filters mention 2MM keys as being "small."

In that case, I am looking for a bloom filter variant tuned for *very small* datasets; in the range of 100-10,000 elements. I am working on a distributed storage system where I would have many thousands or millions of these filters and need them to be very compact.

Actually, I know at construction time the entire universe of <50,000 keys that would ever be queried for each filter — where each filter has a slightly different universe.

---

My plan — if I can't find a specialized variant — is to implement some [Xor](https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.08258), [Binary Fuse](https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.01174), and [Cuckoo](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.06067) variants and tune the parameters myself.

But before I do, I would like to know if I have a knowledge gap or am missing some search term for small data sets.